# 'Emgu.CV.Capture' does not contain a definition for 'GrabProcessState'

Tags: c#, dll, emgucv

I work with EmguCV 2.9.0.1922 (x86, x64) and try to play a video file. I took one of Emgu-video-example from internet (EmguCV 2.4.2...) and can't even compile it: 'Emgu.CV.Capture' does not contain a definition for `GrabProcessState`. (Does Emgu.CV.dll crucially change between version 2.4 and 2.9??)

In the case I go to the EmguCV 2.4.2 compilation is OK, but runtime error is:
"A first chance exception of type `System.DllNotFoundException` occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
A first chance exception of type `System.TypeInitializationException` occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
An unhandled exception of type `System.TypeInitializationException` occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for `Emgu.CV.CvInvoke` threw an exception."

Comment: Are you connected unmanaged code? For 2.4.2 this example works fine for me.